# Pass json data to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Probably a simple one for an expert:

I have a json file called newport.json located in the www folder. The json is as follows:

```
{"nmech":"3.00","nelect":"3.00","nplant":"0.00","ncivil":"55.00"}
```

I have my JS to load in via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'newport.json',
    datatype:'json',
    type:'get',
    cache:false,
    success:function(data){
        $(data).each(function(index,value){
                console.log(value);

        });
    }
});
```

My issue is the console log produces the following from the above js:

```
Object {nmech: "3.00", nelect: "3.00", nplant: "0.00", ncivil: "55.00"}
```

but I seem to be struggling to then get a value say nmech passed into a javascript variable.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is your question? `data` should have your `Object` `console.log(data.nmech);` should produce `3.00`...

Comment: So in order to get that particular value, it would be `data.nmech` *without* the each loop. do you have multiples of these or is it just this?

Comment: yes I can use data.nmech and output to the console and it shows 3.00. My question is how would I pass this value to a variable.

Comment: `var nmech = data.nmech`

Comment: @JeremyJackson I have tried this and get the following error in the console - Uncaught ReferenceError: nmech is not defined.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to get that so we can help you better.

Comment: This is an asynchronous call. So you may set a variable in the `success` function but the variable won't actually be set until the `success` function callback gets called. So if you set `data.nmech` to a global variable in the `success` function and immediately print that variable to the console after your `ajax` call it will more than likely be `undefined` because the call hasn't completed yet. If you used `setTimeout()` and printed it after say 3 seconds it probably won't be `undefined`...

Comment: @KevinSullivan google ajax asynchronous for more information on how asynchronous calls work.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is an *object*, not *array*. As soon as you don't have anything to enumerate, $.each doen's make much sense here.

To to access you properties you need:

```
var nmech = data.nmech;
var nelect = data.nelect;
```

etc

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ it will work with an `object`...key/value pairs.

Comment: @brso05 you are perfectly right. Main point was that it doesn't make much sense in that situation. I'll update answer.

Comment: @brso05 Fillde with some particular code would make life much easier

Answer (score 0):

As there is a single object that is returned, the loop only runs once. I believe what you are trying to do is to enumerate the properties of that single object. So this:

```
for (var propertyName in data) { console.log(data[propertyName]; }
```